# R.java file contains an error and i cant delete it

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I made a mistake and misnamed a TextView in the rumney forum class and now thr R.java file contains this variable. I have deleted all the rumney forum, rumney forum card and 2 pages but the error wont delete. I did a search and can only find this variable in the R.java file so im confussed? This error wont let me run my programme at all so please help :)

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

In android studio I usually get this done by clicking the "Sync project with gradle files" button and then on the top menu: Build > Clean Project  and then Build > Rebuild Project.